# How to use SDL_KeyCode to handle a key press each time?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to generate a rectangle into a new position whenever I press the Right arrow key, I was able to get the 1st rectangle but now stuck at the 2nd one. As this is not a case of SDL_GetKeyboardState (to move the rectangle when key is pressed continuously), I'm completely clueless on how this should proceed. To create array for rectangles and pass it to poll event?

```
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Event e;
SDL_Rect one, two;
bool quit = false;

void init(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Testing", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                               SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
                                               SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);  
}

void draw(){
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);      
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &one);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 66, 255, 255);     
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &two);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);    
}


void logic(){
    Uint8 *state;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) !=0) {
        if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    one = {2,2,124,124};
                    //two = {130,2,124,124};
                    break;
                    
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    one = {0,0,0,0};
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    init();
    while (!quit)
    {
        logic();
        draw();
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    renderer = NULL;
    window = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entierly sure what you're asking. Do you want to randomly generate a new rectangle on screen each time you press a key? Then you need to keep track how many time you pressed that key, and grow a array of rect ; then your draw method could just display that list of rectangles, knowing the size of it.

Comment: By the way, you have a lot of dead code. `screen` doesn't do anything, as the variable `state`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try out your suggestion first

Comment: Quick followup... Did it work?